# reactjs route.... Refreshing page issues

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, routes

I have this below code.... When I go to the / directory it is fine. Then if I go to /cats it works but if I hit f5 it throw a 404 error saying page cannot be found. From reading online I see ppl have added a htaccess file to the public directory but that did not help me

```
render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/index" />
        <Route path="/index" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/dogs" component={Dogs}/>
        <Route path="/cats" component={Cats}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: You need to make sure your server is serving the `index.html` file for every route in your app, so that React Router can take care of the routing in the browser.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: It's hard to say with the information currently in your question. You could research how to do that with the technology you are using.